# Group() not recognized as an opaque type in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a function with an if statement that in either case returns a `Group()`, however, SwiftUI compiler doesn't recognize it as the same type. What's going on?

Getting error:

> Function declares an opaque return type, but the return statements in
> its body do not have matching underlying types

```
private func cellWithContact(_ contact: CNContact) -> some View {
    let displayName: String? = CNContactFormatter.string(from: contact, style: .fullName)
    if let displayName = displayName {
        return Group() {
            Text(displayName)
        }
    }
    return Group() {}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Opaque types still require there to be a concrete single type specified by a callee, but in your function you have two different return types:

```
return Group { Text(displayName) } // Group<Text> type
// and also
return Group { }                   // Group<EmptyView> type
```

So, you need to either

1. Use a type-erased `AnyView`:

```
return AnyView(Group { Text(displayName) }  // AnyView type
// ...
return AnyView(Group { })                   // AnyView type
```

2. Ensure that they are the same type, by changing the empty one to:

```
return Group { Text("") }  // Group<Text> type, same as the other one
```

3. Return a conditional (`_ConditionalContent`) view, which ViewBuilder creates automatically when encountering an `if/else`:

```
@ViewBuilder // this is required
func cellWithContact(_ contact: CNContact) -> some View {
   // ...
   if someCondition { // _ConditionalContent<Group<Text>, Group<EmptyView>> type
      Group { Text(...) }
   } else {
      Group { }
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! First time seeing that `@ViewBuilder` is required, is that iOS14+? I will look into it, but most of my view builder functions didn't have that 

Comment: No, it was available since the beginning of SwiftUI. This is *how* SwiftUI allows us to write views in a declarative way, where it's just a bunch of view statements and conditionals that "magically" produce a composite view

Answer (score 1):

Here is possible solution. Tested with Xcode 12 / iOS 14.

```
@ViewBuilder
private func cellWithContact(_ contact: CNContact) -> some View {
    let displayName: String? = CNContactFormatter.string(from: contact, style: .fullName)
    if let displayName = displayName {
        Text(displayName)
    } else {
        EmptyView()  // or `Group {}`, but it is the same
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Other answers are perfectly fine. Just wanted to mention that if you're using **SwiftUI 2 / iOS 14** you can use control flow statements (like `if-let`) directly in a `@ViewBuilder` block:

```
@ViewBuilder
private func cellWithContact(_ contact: CNContact) -> some View {
    if let displayName = CNContactFormatter.string(from: contact, style: .fullName) {
        Text(displayName)
    }
}
```

And there’s no need to return `EmptyView()` which makes the code much cleaner.